# Выключение/включение Бд Oracle по времени

Tags: oracle, windows-server-2012

Как можно останавливать и запускать экземпляр бд по заданному времени в ОС Windows server 2012 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для решения данной задачи можно воспользоваться **.bat** скриптом и добавить его в "Планировщик заданий".

Cкрипт на запуск выгляди так:

```
@echo off
sqlplus login/pass as sysdba @c:\start.sql 
exit;
```

в **start.sql** файле пишем:

```
STARTUP MOUNT;
```

На остановку :

```
@echo off
sqlplus login/pass as sysdba @c:\stop.sql 
exit;
```

**stop.sql :**

```
SHUTDOWN NORMAL;
```

Comment: Чтобы дополнить свой вопрос, просим вас воспользоваться опцией редактирования. Кнопку «Опубликовать ответ» следует использовать только для исчерпывающих ответов на вопросы. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/336541)

Comment: @Dmitriy Уважаемый в чем проблема ? Я задал вопрос тут, мне на него не ответили я нашел ответ в другом месте и поделился здесь. Возможно кто-то в будущем столкнется с таким же вопросом. В чем проблема ?

Comment: Где вы увидели дополнение или продолжение моего вопроса ??

Comment: Во-первых, непонятно, это опубликовано как ответ или как дополнение к вопросу (вы не поверите, но огромное количество людей делает так). Я понял так, что вы дописали это как пояснение - что вам нужен скрипт для планировщика заданий Windows. Тут кстати существенный момент - в большинстве случаев оракл работает на линуксе, и если у вас другая ОС, неплохо бы это упомянуть в вопросе. Во-вторых, ответом это не является, потому что о существовании планировщиков (в любой ОС) обычно любой знает, а сам скрипт написать как правило сложнее, чем узнать о существовании планировщика.

Comment: @Dmitriy вы в вопросе явно видите "помогите написать скрипт.." ? Нужны были идеи по автоматизации запуска и выключения о чем было написано это 1-е. Второе это то что я надеялся на то что есть встроенный планировщик в самой БД. Третье максимум в чем вижу свою ошибку это в том что я не указал на какой ОС стоит БД. А если например человек не знает о планировщике или не берёт это во внимание ? Возможно найдутся люди которым это поможет.

Comment: @Dmitriy это ответ, просто не достаточно полный. [Любой ответ, который направляет в нужное русло, является ценным](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Ethernets стоит давать более развернутые ответы, это поможет другим участникам с той же проблемой. Просто приведите пример скрипта - этим вы поможете кому-то в будущем и избавите его от необходимости гуглить "как запустить сервис из командной строки" :)

Comment: @PashaPash В ближайшее время исправлю. Спасибо за помощь и подсказку. Хорошего дня.